# how to update time when multiple entries present for same time stamp

Tags: r, count, repeat

I have data as follows:

```
datetime <- c('2018-01-01 08:00','2018-01-01 08:01:00','2018-01-01 08:02:00', '2018-01-01 08:02:00', '2018-01-01 08:03:00')
from <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
to <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(datetime, from, to)

df
             datetime from to
1    2018-01-01 08:00    1  0
2 2018-01-01 08:01:00    0  1
3 2018-01-01 08:02:00    1  0
4 2018-01-01 08:02:00    0  1
5 2018-01-01 08:03:00    1  0
```

There are 2 entries corresponding to '2018-01-01 08:02:00'.

For these two entries, I want to update the time to '2018-01-01 08:02:00' and '2018-01-01 08:02:30' respectively.

There may be more than two such entries corresponding to a time stamp.
So the 60 sec interval will be divided by the number of repeats, and the time stamp updated accordingly.

What is the best way to update the time for all such entries?

I can count the number of repeats for each time instance using:

```
 sum(df$datetime == '2018-01-01 08:02:00')
```

But I am unsure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if this is the most efficient method to do this however, I think this would work.

For each unique `datetime` entry we calculate it's frequency and then generate a sequence of `freq` equi-distant entries.

```
df$datetime[] <- unlist(sapply(unique(df$datetime), function(x) {
                 freq = sum(x==df$datetime)
                 as.character(seq(as.POSIXct(x), by = 60/freq, length.out = freq))
                 }))


df
#             datetime from to
#1 2018-01-01 08:00:00    1  0
#2 2018-01-01 08:01:00    0  1
#3 2018-01-01 08:02:00    1  0
#4 2018-01-01 08:02:30    0  1
#5 2018-01-01 08:03:00    1  0
```

Comment: original dataframe has 1236 rows. Frequency calculation works fine, but running the entire command gives: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "new", value = character(0)) :   replacement has 0 rows, data has 1236.

Comment: @Sree Can you share a sample dataframe from which I can reproduce the error? This works fine on the sample dataset you have provided.

Comment: it worked upon replacing df$datetime[ ] with df$datetime on the left hand side. I got the error msg with the original assignment. Could you please check which assignment worked for you? Thanks for the solution.

Comment: After running this code, the dateTime "2018-01-10 00:00:00" for an entry is converted to "2018-01-10". Any idea why and how to correct? The code has to run for a large number of days, it is not possible to check manually for an incorrect entry.